# PUT update Backand object field float bigger than 1000000 sets object field value to 1000000

Tags: backand

When PUT change a record of type float, with a value over 1000000 the value gets changed to 1000000.

Comment: Fixed by Itay from Back& ... " you can create new field (or delete the existing one and re-add it) and it will save large numbers" - THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed, see Antonio comment above